# Using PHP for Highchart Heatmap

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts

I have some questions.
I'm trying to display my data in Heatmap, like: ['2020-02-12', '12', 9] ['2020-02-13', '13', 12]. x is the date, y is the week, and value is the data.

I converted to ['2', '12', 9] ['2', '13', 12]. x is the month and y is the date.

I use PHP to grab the data, and then use js to display. But nothing is displayed.

This is my code:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com.cn/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com.cn/highcharts/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com.cn/highcharts/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="https://img.hcharts.cn/highcharts-plugins/highcharts-zh_CN.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/highcharts/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/highcharts/plugins/export/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/highcharts/js/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

 Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'heatmap',
            marginTop: 40,
            marginBottom: 80,
            plotBorderWidth: 1
        },
        title: {
            text: 'air'
        },
        xAxis: {
            max:31,
            categories: ['2020-01', '2020-02','2020-03'],
            title:{
                text:"Date"
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            categories: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7','8',
              '9', '10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18',
              '19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28',
              '29','30','31'],
            title: null
        },
        colorAxis: {
            stops: [
                [0, "#28FF28"],
                [0.2, "#FFDC35"],
                [0.4, "#FF8000"],
                [0.6, "#EA0000"],
                [0.8, "#9F4D95"],
                [1, "#750000"]
            ],
            min: 0,
            max:300
            // min: 0,
            // minColor: '#FFDC35',
            // maxColor: '#EA0000'
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            layout: 'vertical',
            margin: 0,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25,
            symbolHeight: 280
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b> sold <br><b>' +
                    this.point.value + '</b> items on <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'air_data',
            borderWidth: 1,
            data:<?php echo $data; ?>,
            turboThreshold:0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: '#000000'
            }
        }]
</script>
```

And this is my php code:

```
if ($stmt = $db->query($sql)) {
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)) {
        $arr[] = array(
            date("n", strtotime($result['date'])),
            date("d", strtotime($result['date'])),
            intval($result['pm25'])
        );
    }
    $data = json_encode($arr);
    echo $data;
}
```

I want to show like this photo
[image: heatmap]

Answer (score 1):

In the javascript side, a couple of steps are needed to use the json data.

Assuming the structure of data is valid (enough) to load the chart as you show it,
use something like this code illustrates:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  // json string into js var 
  var plainJson = '<?php echo $data; ?>';
  var jsData = JSON.parse(plainJson);

  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        marginTop: 40,
        marginBottom: 80,
        plotBorderWidth: 1
     ...
    series: [{
        name: 'air_data',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: jsData,  // use jsData in chart
        turboThreshold:0,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000'
        }
    }]
</script>
```

**Update**

As you mentioned in comments, it seems the natural number of the month is not extracted from the "02" string.
The map needs numerical data, so let's convert it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var                                     // declare all vars at once
      plainJson = '<?php echo $data; ?>', // json string into js var 
      jsData = JSON.parse(plainJson),     // string to js obj 
      parsedData = [],
      i
      ;

  // convert string values to integers
  for(i in jsData) {
      parsedData.push({
          month: parseInt(jsData[i].month, 10),
          day: parseInt(jsData[i].day, 10),
          value: jsData[i].value  // value is ok
      })
  }

  Highcharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        ...
      series: [{
        name: 'air_data',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: parsedData,  // use parsedData in chart
        ...
  }]
</script>
```

Comment: I used plainJson to display: {"month": "3", "day": "02", "value": 6}, using JSON.parse to become [object Object].
Although the heatmap can be displayed, the content is [0,6] [1,17] [2,15], the values ​​of 6,17,15 are correct, and the previous ones are incorrect.

Comment: I see, if the issue on your [0, 6], comes from `{"month": "3", "day": "02", "value": 6}` that means the "02" value is converted to a "0", instead of a natural "2". This could be a wrong String to Integer conversion. 
try to get the values from your climate data formatted properly, with a little bit more of processing. (I'll update the answer with the idea)

Comment: In case the updated solution doesn't work, coud you please edit the question, and add the output of `console.dir(jsData)` ?